# iIam trying to display the result of a geolocation javascript function in an input field

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js, geolocation

```
<script>
    function showPosition() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                var latx = position.coords.latitude;
                var lonx = position.coords.longitude;
                var positionInfo = "(" + "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + ", " + "Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude + ")";
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = positionInfo;
                document.getElementById("latx") = latx;
                document.getElementById("lonx") = lonx;
            });
        } else {
            alert("Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 geolocation.");
        }

    }
</script>
```

> Blockquote
>   Blockquote
>   Blockquote

I want it to be displayed in my form in the latxx and the lonxx field but its not working
and doesnt even show but the result is displayed in the div

```
<form action="addads.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input class="kolo" type="text" name="ProTitle" placeholder="Title" alt="wating"
           title="Pleaes            write Your Title" require>
    <textarea placeholder="Detalis" name="ProDetalis" id="my-input" class="form-control " rows="5"></textarea>
    <input class="kolo" type="text" name="Proprice" placeholder="price" alt="wating" title="Pleaes write Your price"
           require>
    <div id="result">
        <!--Position information will be inserted here-->
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="latxx" id="latxx" value=""/>
    <input type="text" name="lonxx" id="lonxx" value=""/>
    <button type="button" onclick="showPosition();">Show Position</button>
    <input class="kolo" type="file" name="image">
    <select class="kolo" name="Maincategory">
        <?php
        $resultcategories = mysqli_query($clink, "SELECT CategoryID , CategoryName FROM categories");
        while ($rowcategories = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultcategories)) {
            echo "<option value='{$rowcategories['CategoryID']}'>{$rowcategories['CategoryName']} </option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="save">
</form>
```

Comment: You can set the value of an input like: `document.getElementById("latx").value = latx`. (Note that in your html the id is `"latxx"` and in the js `"latx"` so you would need to change that.)

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("latxx").value = latx;
document.getElementById("lonxx").value = lonx;
```

Can you try that in the js?